# TNTmips orthorectification capability?

Tags: tntmips

I have been an ENVI and ArcGIS user, but recently heard about the TNTmips from MicroImages. I would like to know:

How does TNTmips handle orthorectification? Can it orthorectify multiple images over a large area in the same process?

The data involved is a series of georectified aerial images.

Comment: This is an open-ended question that is primarily based on opinion.  Please edit the question to include more specifics as to use cases and data involved, or ask over in the chat room, which doesn't have the same requirements.

Comment: There is a whole web site about TNTmips with a Contact us button http://www.microimages.com/products/tntmips.htm. If you are a potential customer they for sure will give you this information.